# Magento - Retrieve highest product price in current collection from layered nav

Tags: magento, filter

Layered navigation filters are created in

```
app/design/frontend/base/theme/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml
```

How can I retrieve the value of the highest product price in the current product collection from within this file?

I've tried what I thought was the obvious choice `$this->getMaxPriceInt()` from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price` but that does not seem to work within filter.phtml.

Comment: I don't think so the layered navigation load all of product pricess that you visited catalog. In my opinion, the system filter the products that you selected price range. Therefore, the MaxPrice should not be available

Comment: According to the Magento wiki : `Price ranges are also logically picked to display as another filter.  The ranges themselves are determined by the prices of products contained within.  There will never be more than 10 price ranges displayed, and products will be distributed accordingly.`

Comment: check this topic [How do I Change price filter](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/65135/P15/)

Comment: Hi Oğuz,  I accept that the collection is already filtered by the time the layered nav is being rendered and that I need an alternative way of retrieving the max price.  For this reason i decided instead to create another collection for the same category, sorted by price and limited to 1 record.  Problem now is when I try to get the product price it results in an error: `Call to undefined method Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Product_Collection::getPrice()`

Comment: @Oğuz Çelikdemir: This is the code I'm using to retrieve the collection:  `$catid=2; 
 $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
 $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
  ->addCategoryFilter($cat)
  ->setStoreId($storeId)
  ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
  ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
  ->setPage(1, 1);
 $highprice=999;//$products->getDescription();`

Comment: @Oğuz Çelikdemir: One other thing - in order to get the currently selected category I normally would use `Mage::registry('current_category')` but in this case it causes Magento to generate an error report.  Why can't I use this or `$product->getPrice()` in `filter.phtml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming $collection is a collection of 'catalog/product', this should do the trick:

```
$product = $collection->setOrder('price', 'DESC')->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried the following `$catid=2; $visibility = array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH);
 $highprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('final_price')->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)->setOrder('price', 'DESC')->getFirstItem();` but it returns '1' and my max price ought to be more like £500?  Also do you have any idea why `Mage::registry('current_category')` generates an error?

Comment: Try without ->addAttributeToSelect('final_price')

Comment: As for the error, I don't know. What are you trying to do with it? What's the error?

Comment: removing the `->addAttributeToSelect('final_price')` results in the same value Mike. Weird.  I wanted to use `->addAttributeToSelect('final_price')` to set the category ID dynamically.

Comment: the error generated is `a:5:{i:0;s:203:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 

MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1";i:1;s:4334:"#0 /home/gp/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): 

Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)`

Comment: I tried my code and had no trouble with it. Are you sure the collection you're returning is valid? Keep in mind that my original code results in a product object. You'll need to call `$product->getPrice()` to return the price.

Comment: oops! I'd removed the `->getPrice()` and forgotten to add it back... Now it works ;)  Any ideas re the `Mage::registry('current_category')` error?  Thank you!

Comment: Never mind - I found an alternative that works in layered nav: `$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
 $_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
 $catid= $_category->getId();`
 Thank you for your help Mike!

Comment: Complete solution:  `$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
 $_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
 $catid= $_category->getId();
 $visibility = array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH);
 $highprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid)->getProductCollection()
   ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
   ->setOrder('price', 'DESC')
   ->getFirstItem()
   ->getPrice();`

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

Get highest and lowest price in category listing you can use below code.

```
$min_price = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory(Mage::registry('current_category'))->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();
$max_price = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory(Mage::registry('current_category'))->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
```

But it is not working for search and advance search layer navigation.so you can use below code for all pages layer navigation.

```
$min_price = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();
$max_price = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
```

You can use below code on `app/design/frontend/THEME/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml` file.

Comment: Thanks Himansu, it helps me to find min price in search page. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this ( let me know the result )

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$collection = $model->getCollection()
   ->addStoreFilter()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
   ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc');

if(!emtpy($collection)):
   foreach($collection as $products) {
      echo $products->getPrice();
      echo $products->getName();
   }
endif;
```